# Embedding function preserves satisfiablity

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

**Question:**
Let $\sigma$ be a vocabulary where there is only one binary relation symbol $R(\cdot, \cdot)$. Let $N=\langle D^N, R^N\rangle, M=\langle D^M, R^M\rangle $ be two structures for $\sigma$. An function $f: D^M \rightarrow D^N$ is called an *embedding function* if $\forall a,b\in D^M: (a,b)\in R^M \iff (f(a),f(b))\in R^N$. If there exists an embedding function from M to N prove that if an existential statement is satisfiable in M $\iff$ it is satisfiable in $N$:

**My proof:**

- Denote $\phi= \exists x_1\ldots x_n \psi$
- Denote $v'=$ the assignment s.t given an assignment v : $M,v \vDash \phi$ , then v' $\forall 1 \le i \le n : x_i=f(v(x_i))$
- I'll prove that $N,v \vDash \phi$ by induction on the structure of the statement $\psi$:

Base case: if $\psi =R(s_1,s_2)$ (for some terms $s_1, s_2$)
then $v(R^M (s_1^M, s_2^M))=T \iff v'(R^N ([f(s_1)]^N, [f(s_2)]^N)=T$ (this is true from the definition of an embedding function).

Closure: let $\alpha, \beta$ be statements and $\operatorname{op}=\{\land, \lor, \rightarrow\}$,

- if $\psi=\alpha \operatorname{op} \beta$ then $M,v\vDash \alpha \operatorname{op} \beta \iff (M,v \vDash \alpha) \operatorname{op} (M,v \vDash \beta) \iff (N,v' \vDash \alpha) \operatorname{op} (N,v' \vDash \beta)$ (from the induction hypothesis) $\iff N,v' \vDash \alpha \operatorname{op} \beta$
- if $\psi=\neg \alpha$ then proof is very similar to previous case.
- Let $Q\in\{\forall, \exists\}$. if $\psi= Qx \alpha$ (WLOG x is one variable, it could be many but the proof is similar, just with more replacements) then
  $Qd \in D^M : M,v[d/x] \vDash \alpha \iff Qd'\in D^N: d'=f(d): N,v'[d'/x]\vDash \alpha$ (from the definition of embedding function) $\iff
  N,v'\vDash Qx\alpha$

I was wondering if this proof is correct, this is the first time I've been dealing with such proofs in this subject. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I changed $N=< D^N, R^N>$ to $N=\langle D^N, R^N\rangle$ and {$\forall,\exists$} to $\{\forall,\exists\}$.  That is standard usage. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement you are trying to prove is false.

Take $M$ to be the complete graph on 3 vertices, $N$ the complete graph on 4 vertices. Then

- $M$ embeds into $N$,
- but the formula "there are four distinct elements" is an existential sentence true in $N$ but false in $M$.

From this, do you see where your proof breaks down?

Comment: so what you're saying is that this can be proved only in one direction, but not on both directions?

Comment: @user1685224 yes, that's right. Existential sentences are only guaranteed to be preserved upwards, that is from the smaller to the larger. Note that more complex sentences - e.g. $\forall\exists$ - need not be preserved in either direction.

Comment: but how do phrase this formula with only binary one relation symbol R? According to your definition we've already used R to describe existance of an edge between two vertices.

Comment: @user1685224 I was assuming that "=" is included as a logical symbol. Are you not allowed to use "="? If you want to avoid using "=", just take $M$ to be the structure with elements $\{a, b\}$ and $R^M=\emptyset$ and $N$ to be the structure $\{c, d, e\}$ and $R^N=\{(d, e)\}$. Then "$\exists x\exists y(xRy)$" is an existential sentence true in $N$ but not $M$, but $M$ embeds into $N$ via $a\mapsto c, b\mapsto d$.

Comment: Thanks for the example, this one convinced me :-). One last question: for the true direction of the statement, is my proof correct?